# Sencha Architect/Touch nested list issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, nested-lists, sencha-architect, tree-structure

Hello,

I am working with sencha architect, in a touch 2.4 project. I have a issue dealing with nested list and tree store:

- This is my store:

  ```
  Ext.define('App.store.Tree', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

  requires: [
  'App.model.Servicios',
  'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
  'Ext.data.reader.Json',
  'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'
  ],


  config: {
      model: 'App.model.Servicios',
      storeId: 'Tree',
      defaultRootProperty: 'items',
      proxy: {
          type: 'ajax',
          type: 'localstorage',
          reader: {
              type: 'json'
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  });

(I've tried with every combination of proxys and readers and the error is the same.)

- Now this is my model :

  ```
      Ext.define('App.model.Servicios', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Model',


      requires: [
      'Ext.data.Field'
      ],


      config: {
      fields: [
      {
      name: 'categoria',
      type: 'string'
      },
      {
      name: 'nombre',
      type: 'string'
      },
      {
      name: 'ubicacion',
      type: 'string'
      },
      {
      name: 'datos',
      type: 'string'
      }
      ]
      }
      });
  ```
- This is the container with the nested list:

  ```
      Ext.define('App.view.ServiciosContainer', {
      extend: 'Ext.Container',
      alias: 'widget.servicioscontainer',


      requires: [
      'Ext.Toolbar',
      'Ext.Button',
      'Ext.dataview.NestedList'
      ],


      config: {
      height: '100%',
      id: 'ServiciosContainer',
      width: '100%',
      layout: 'fit',
      items: [
      {
      xtype: 'toolbar',
      docked: 'top',
      items: [
      {
      xtype: 'button',
      id: 'serviciosContainerHome',
      iconCls: 'list'
      },
      {
      xtype: 'button',
      id: 'serviciosContainerBorrar',
      iconCls: 'trash'
      },
      {
      xtype: 'button',
      id: 'serviciosContainerAgregar',
      iconCls: 'add'
      }
      ]
      },
      {
      xtype: 'nestedlist',
      id: 'lstServicios',
      displayField: 'nombre',
      store: 'Tree'
      }
      ]
      },


      });
  ```

  - The add button does the following:

    ```
    var data = {
        items: [
            {
            nombre: '1',
            items: [{
                    nombre: '1.1',
                    items: [{
                            nombre: '1.1.1 last',
                            leaf: true
                    }, {
            nombre: '1.1.2 last',
            leaf: true
            }]
    }, {
            nombre: '1.2 last',
            leaf: true
            }]
    },
    {
            nombre: '2',
            items: [{
                    nombre: '2.1 last',
                    leaf: true
            }, {
            nombre: '2.2 last',
            leaf: true
            }]
    }
    ]
    };



    var servicios = Ext.getStore('TreeStore');
    servicios.add(data);
    ```
- This is the error I get when I try to add data to the store:

  ```
      TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'children.length')
  ```

Please Help!!!! I don't know where to look for mistakes as all the examples i've found where identical to mine and they didn't have any problem..

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo using ur code ,its works fine.

i have seen lots of un-needed code in ur demo ,Like you have added proxy to the store etc.

But i clearly see a minor mistake you made # See storeId its "Tree" and look at  Ext.getStore('TreeStore');

I hope you got my point

Thanks